# Find the position to insert an element into a sorted array

Tags: python, algorithm

Problem: Find the position to insert an element into a sorted array

```
A[1] > A[2] > A[3] > ... > A[ n ]
```

1. Show the best and worst case.
2. Write an algorithm to solve the problem

My answer:

The best case is T(n) = 1 in other words in a first position where n is the size of elements. The worst case will be T(n) = n + 1 in other words the last position + 1.

```
  def find_position(element, l):
        i = 0
        inserted = False
        for item in l:
            if element < item:
                inserted =  True
                break
            i = i +1
        if not inserted:
            return len(l)
        else:
            return i
```

Some other students had written a binary search that the worst case is better than mine and told me that my answer is incorrect. But I disagree because the exercise was not explicit to write an optimized algorithm.

Is there any mistake in my logic?

Comment: You don't actually insert anything. Also, best and worst cases don't make sense without reference to a specific algorithm, so part 1 isn't a well-formed question.

Comment: Sorry, but I fixed the teacher answer, had a translation error. In portuguese is: "Considere o problema de encontrar a posição de inserção de um novo elemento em um conjunto ordenado:"

Answer (score 0):

Given what you said where the conditions are simply:

1)write an algorithm to solve a problem
2)analyze the asymptotic complexity of said problem

You clearly did those. Your solution is just the obvious one, not the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it falls in after the number(something like below..)

```
for l in range(0, len(lst)):
    if lst[l] >= number_to_be_inserted:
        lst.insert(l+1, number_to_be_inserted)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary search has a best case efficiency of O(1) and worst case (average case) efficiency is O(log n).

```
public static int searchInsert(int[] nums, int target) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = nums.length - 1;

    if (nums[end] < target) {
        return end + 1;
    } else if (nums[start] >= target) {
        return start;
    }

    while (start < end) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (nums[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        } else if(nums[mid] < target) {
            start = mid + 1;
        } else {
            end = mid;
        }
    }
    return end;
}
```